# Data Store In excel using pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas, selenium, store

I wrote code to store data in excel using pandas. File is created .Headers are also show but data in this file are not relevant.

```
 from selenium import webdriver
    import time
    import pandas as pd
    
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\Program Files\Python39\libs\chromedriver.exe")
    driver.maximize_window()
    url = ("https://foxy.com/what-we-grow")
    driver.get(url)
    
    
    Vegetables_Name = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//span[@class="title"]')
    for name in Vegetables_Name:
        print("Vegetable Name:",name.text)
    
    
    Total_Vegetables = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//span[@class="title"]')
    
    print("Total Vegetables:",(len(Total_Vegetables)),"\n")
    
    
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    time.sleep(10)
    
    Vegetables_Images = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('source')
    for image in Vegetables_Images:
        print("Image Url",image.get_attribute('srcset'))
    
    
    
    Total_Vegetables_images =  driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('source')
    print("Total Vegetables_images:",(len(Total_Vegetables_images)),"\n")
    
    
    df = pd.DataFrame({'Vegetable Name ':Vegetables_Name,'Vegetable Images ':Vegetables_Images})
    df.to_csv('Usama.csv', index=False, encoding='utf-8')
```

data that is stored in excel file

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After

```
Vegetables_Name = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//span[@class="title"]')
for name in Vegetables_Name:
    print("Vegetable Name:",name.text)
```

`Vegetables_Name` is `list` of elements found by selenium, if you want to store names you need to extract name i.e. replace code above with

```
Vegetables_Name = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//span[@class="title"]')
Vegetables_Name = [i.text for i in Vegetables_Name]
for name in Vegetables_Name:
    print("Vegetable Name:",name)
```

And you need to undertake similar action for images, but using `.get_attribute('srcset')` rather than accessing `.text`

Comment: Really Really Thank You so much . Its working